# Failure to change key mapping with loadkeys in systemd service

Tags: fedora, keyboard-shortcuts, systemd-unit

My Packard-Bell laptop keyboard has 2 non-standard keys grouped with the navigation arrows making a 2-rows x 3-columns sub-block instead of the traditional inverted-T. Of course, these keys are not recognised by off-the-shelf Linux kernel.

I can make them active with `setkeycodes` and `loadkeys` commands as root.

To avoid having to launch manually the command(s), I designed a systemd unit (a .service file) so that the keyboard is configured during startup.

This worked fine until recently when I upgraded my laptop from a very old Fedora release to Fedora 35.

I now get "keymap x: permission denied" on all maps I try to modify. I don't understand why.

Unless I'm wrong, all commands launched by system systemd services are run as root. As such, loadkeys should have access to any file (I had to move the mapping file to /etc from my user directory to fix a "no such file or directory" error) and be able to change the console mapping.

Fearing a possible race condition, I changed the dependency so that the service is started after multi-user.target is reached (instead of some time before) and I am sure that every partition is mounted and ready. But this did not fix the error.

<del>I suspect my service is run under some non-privileged user but I can't guess which (I can't use `id` or `whoami` because the commands are not interpreted by a shell and I can't redirect output to some file for later use).</del>

<del>Man says there is no use to add User= or Group= because units are already owned by root.</del>

UPDATE: I was able to check that the service is launched as `root`. Consequently, the *Keymap x: permission denied* doesn't make sense. And if I run the command directly as root (not through `systemctl`), `loadkeys` works fine.

So what? Can you point me into some direction?

Answer (score 0):

user:

```
$ localectl set-keymap 'YourKeyboardMapName"
```

and, if selinux,

root:

```
# /sbin/restorecon -v /.hcwd  (to avoid selinux complaints)
```